# How to convert to odt using xparse and mk4ht oolatex

Tags: tex4ht, xparse, open-office

Both `tex4ht` and `htlatex`  compile documents with package `xparse`.

But `mk4ht oolatex` doesn't. Running it on a document as simple as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

raises these errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   ^
l.30 \catcode`\^^
                 A=\catcode`\%
```

and

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   ^
l.479 \Gin@codes
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is an assumption in the LaTeX core `graphics` package. Early on, it includes the lines

```
\edef\Gin@codes{%
 \catcode`\noexpand\^^A\the\catcode`\^^A\relax
 \catcode`\noexpand\"\the\catcode`\"\relax
 \catcode`\noexpand\*\the\catcode`\*\relax
 \catcode`\noexpand\!\the\catcode`\!\relax
 \catcode`\noexpand\:\the\catcode`\:\relax}
\catcode`\^^A=\catcode`\%
```

which are intended to save category codes of various items, then alter the catcode of `^^A` (which is then used to set up some debug code). The problem is that the `^^A` input syntax only works if `^` is a math superscript character (catcode 7). That's almost always the case, but running `mk4ht oolatex` sets the category code of `^` to 12 ('other').

(You see the issue with `xparse` as it loads `expl3`, and that in turn loads `graphics`. However, you can see the issue just loading `graphics` alone, so this is not an `xparse` issue *per se*.)

Some information on how `tex4ht` handles super- and subscripts can be found in [trouble shooting](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn3.html#QQ1-3-14) section on `tex4ht` site. For suppression of subscripts redefinitions, you can use `no^` command line option. So for your file, this should compile without errors:

```
mk4ht oolatex filename "xhtml, no^"
```

For overview of available options, see [this article](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=504)

Comment: I cannot test it now, but there is command line option `no^` for tex4ht which suppresses making `^` active. but I don't know if `oolatex` supports this option

Comment: Running `mk4ht oolatex filename "xhtml, no^"`, sample file compiles without errors.

Comment: @JosephWright can't possibly be a bug in graphics:-) More to the point the same ^^ convention is used in doc.sty inputenc latexsym and several other parts of the base latex distribution

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not a bug perhaps, but odd that the code is defensive about some things but leaves others which could be covered. Take a look at Heiko's standard lead-in for a really serious example of catcode paranoia.

Comment: yes graphics could add ^ to the characters it normalises, but the assumption that ^ is superscript during package loading is all over the latex code, just as the assumption that \ is the escape character, you have to stop somewhere. Babel delays its shorthands to begin{document} with good reason.

Comment: @michal.h21: Merci ! tex4ht est vivant !